# Generating a Pattern Using Loops in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am attempting to write a Java program that outputs a specific pattern of dots, slashes, and quotation marks based on the value of a variable named SIZE. The challenge I'm facing is how to generate the correct number of quotation marks and other characters based on this SIZE value. Here's the relationship between SIZE and the expected output:

Pattern Breakdown:

Dots: (.): There are always three dots before and after the entire pattern.

Slashes: (/ and ): There's always a forward slash at the start and a backslash at the end, enclosing the quotation marks.

Quotation Marks: (' and "): For each SIZE, there are two sets of quotation marks (' and "). The number of each type of quotation mark seems to grow as SIZE increases. Specifically, for a given SIZE, there are:
SIZE pairs of double quotation marks (").
SIZE + 1 single quotation marks (').

For **`SIZE = 2`**:

```
.../"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\...
/"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\
```

For **`SIZE = 3`**:

```
.../"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\...
/"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\
```

For SIZE = 4:

```
....../"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\......
.../"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\...
/"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\
```

For SIZE = 5:

```
....../"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\......
.../"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\...
/"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\
```

For SIZE = 6:

```
........./"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\.........
....../"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\......
.../"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\...
/"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\
```

For SIZE = 7:

```
........./"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\.........
....../"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\......
.../"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\...
/"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"\
```

Here are the constraints:

1. Only allowed to use **`println/print`** statements, static methods, method calls, loops, nested loops, local variables, and class constants.
2. Not allowed to use method parameters, methods that return values, or conditional statements (i.e., if, if/else statements).

   Here is where I am stuck .
3. ```
    public class PatternGenerator {

    public static final int SIZE = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printPattern();
    }

    public static void printPattern() {
        printTop();
        printMiddle();
    }

    public static void printTop() {
    for (int line = SIZE; line <= SIZE; line++) {
        for (int dot = 0; dot < 3  * ((SIZE + 3) / 3) ; dot++) {
            System.out.print(".");
        }
        System.out.print("/");
        for (int quote = 1; quote <= SIZE * 4 - 1 ; quote++) {
            System.out.print("\"'");
        }
        System.out.print("\"\\");

        for (int dot = 0; dot < 3  * ((SIZE + 3) / 3) ; dot++) {
            System.out.print(".");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
    }
    public static void printMiddle() {
        for (int line = 1; line <= 1; line++) {
            System.out.print("/");
            for (int quote = 1; quote <= (SIZE * 10 / 2 )  ; quote++) {
                System.out.print("\"'");
            }
            System.out.print("\"\\");
        }
    }
   ```

}

Comment: Can you verify what the number of rows to be printed is?  I get `SIZE / 2 +1`, but I'd like that checked for correctness.

Comment: rather than posting the output only, can you post like the pattern/rule of how the output should look depending on the input so that people who dont want to scrutinize each of the `For SIZE = N` wont need to? Like how does it grow?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer That, was me just experimenting but not being able to find a solution. Yes that doesn't have to be there

Comment: @experimentunit1998X I have updated the post to have what you requested

Comment: @markspace It goes from 
SIZE = 2 2 rows 
Size = 3 2 rows 
size = 4 3 rows
size = 5 3 rows 
size = 6 4 rows
size = 7 4 rows

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

    public static final int SIZE = 7;
    public static final int NUM_LINES = SIZE / 2 + 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printPattern();
    }

    public static void printPattern() {
        for (int line = 0; line < NUM_LINES ; line++) {

            // 3 * ((SIZE - 2 * line) / 2) is the number of the starting set dots per line
            for (int i = 0; i < 3 * ((SIZE - 2 * line) / 2); i++) {
                System.out.print(".");
            }

            System.out.print("/");

            // (10 * SIZE + 3) is the total number of characters per line
            // - 3 which are the starting / and the ending "\
            // - 2 * (3 * ((SIZE - 2 * line) / 2)) which is the total number of dots per line
            // The result is divided by 2 to get the number of "' pairs
            for (int i = 0; i < ((10 * SIZE + 3) - 3 - 2 * (3 * ((SIZE - 2 * line) / 2))) / 2; i++) {
                System.out.print("\"'");
            }

            System.out.print("\"\\");

            // 3 * ((SIZE - 2 * line) / 2) is the number of the ending set dots per line
            for (int i = 0; i < 3 * ((SIZE - 2 * line) / 2); i++) {
                System.out.print(".");
            }

            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Your loops:

```
for (int line = SIZE; line <= SIZE; line++) {
```

and:

```
for (int line = 1; line <= 1; line++) {
```

will both be executed only once: with `line == SIZE` and `line == 1` respectively.

I seems that the number of lines to be printed is equal to `SIZE/2+1`.

The number of dots at the beginning and the end of the line depends on which line is currently being printed, but in your code, it clearly doesn't:

```
 for (int dot = 0; dot < 3  * ((SIZE + 3) / 3) ; dot++) {
```

The number of dots to be printed on the beginning of a line is equal to `3*(LINES-line)` where `LINES` is equal to `SIZE/2+1` as seen above and `line` is the zero-base line number. The same number of dots is printed at the end of the line.

The number of quotes depends on the number of dots, and the number dots itself depends on the line being printed, as seen above.

How about something like this:

```
public class Main {
    private static final int SIZE = 6;
    private static final int LINES = SIZE/2+1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int line = 1; line <= LINES; ++line) {
            int dots = 3*(LINES-line);
            for (int i  = 1; i <= dots; ++i) {
                System.out.print('.');
            }
            System.out.print('/');
            int quotes = 4*SIZE+3*line;
            for (int i = 1; i <= quotes; ++i) {
                System.out.print("\"'");
            }
            System.out.print('"');
            System.out.print('\\');
            for (int i  = 1; i <= dots; ++i) {
                System.out.print('.');
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend

1. a lookup table with precalculated pattern parameters ( NUM_LINES, FIRST_LINE_PATTERNS )
2. clearly named methods that show intent such as dots, pattern, open and close of the run
3. iterate though the lines with for loops, decreasing the number of dots and increasing the size of the pattern

Hope this helps :)

```
    public class Main {
    public static void dots() {
        System.out.print("...");
    }
    
    public static void pattern() {
        System.out.print("\"\'");
    }
    
    public static void open() {
        System.out.print("/");        
    }
    
    public static void close() {
        System.out.print("\"\\");        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int NUM_LINES = 0;
        final int FIRST_LINE_PATTERNS = 1;

        // for a specific size precalcualted number of lines and number of patterns on first line
        final int[][] PARAMS = {
          { 0,0 },  // 0
          { 0,0 },  // 1
          { 2,7 }, // 2
          { 2,10 }, // 3
          { 3,13 }, // 4
          { 3,16 }, // 5
          { 4,19 }, // 6
          { 4,22 }  // 7
        };
        
        final int SIZE = 7;
        
        final int numLines = PARAMS[SIZE][NUM_LINES];
        int num_patterns = PARAMS[SIZE][FIRST_LINE_PATTERNS];
        int num_dotGroups = numLines-1;
        for( int lineIdx = 0; lineIdx < numLines; lineIdx ++) {
            for( int dotGroupIdx = 0; dotGroupIdx < num_dotGroups; dotGroupIdx++) {
                dots();
            }
            open();
            for( int patternIdx = 0; patternIdx < num_patterns; patternIdx++ ) {
                pattern();
            }
            close();
            for( int dotGroupIdx = 0; dotGroupIdx < num_dotGroups; dotGroupIdx++) {
                dots();
            }
            System.out.println();
            
            num_dotGroups--;
            num_patterns+=3;
        }
    }
}
```